# LINQ to XML query in c#

Tags: xml, linq

How can query below document so it would give me value of "id" (the one in the root after status) ?

this gives an error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

```
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(responseString, LoadOptions.None);
                return (from e in document.Root.Elements("status")
                        select e.Element("id").Element("name").Value).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
                return responseString;
            }
        }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<status>
  <created_at>Tue Sep 29 09:33:23 +0000 2009</created_at>
  <id>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</id>
  <text>test</text>
  <source><a href="http://apiwiki.twitter.com/" rel="nofollow"&gt;API</a&gt;</source>
  <truncated>false</truncated>
  <in_reply_to_status_id></in_reply_to_status_id>
  <in_reply_to_user_id></in_reply_to_user_id>
  <favorited>false</favorited>
  <in_reply_to_screen_name></in_reply_to_screen_name>
  <user>
    <id>xxxx</id>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <screen_name>xxx</screen_name>
   </user>
</status>
```

Comment: Please edit this question, just paste your XML as-is into the editor with all the `<` etc intact, just indent it all by at least 4 spaces and SO gets the formating correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root element is already 'status'. Therefore the following code:

```
return (from e in document.Root.Elements("status")
                        select e.Element("id").Element("name").Value).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
```

needs to read:

```
return document.Root.Element("id").Value;
```